# Connecting to Oracle using ODP.NET with Enterprise Library

Tags: c#, .net, database, oracle

I wrote a simple console program that tries to connect to an Oracle database using the Enterprise Library, ODP.NET with written in C# using VS2013. I have ODAC 12.c installed on my PC.

However, my program gets an exception when my program tries to open the 
database.

```
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle;

OracleDatabase db = null;
db2 = DatabaseFactory.CreateDatabase() as OracleDatabase;  

System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException was unhandled
Message=An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for 
dataConfiguration: Could not load file or assembly 
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data, Version=5.0.414.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. 
The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference.
Source=System.Configuration
```

My app.config file contains the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" 
    type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, .../> 
    <section name="oracleConnectionSettings" 
    type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.Configuration.OracleConnectionSettings, ... />
  </configSections>

  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="OracleConnect">
      <providerMappings>
          <add databaseType="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Oracle.OracleDatabase, ... />
      </providerMappings>
  </dataConfiguration>
  <oracleConnectionSettings>
      <add name="Oracle Connection" />
  </oracleConnectionSettings>

  <oracle.manageddataaccess.client>
  <version number="*">
    <dataSources>
      <dataSource alias="sdtp11" descriptor="(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)
      (HOST=servername)(PORT=24106))(CONNECT_DATA=(SID=databasename)(SERVER=DEDICATED)))"/> 
    </dataSources>
   </version>
  </oracle.manageddataaccess.client>

  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OracleConnect" connectionString="Database=databasename;
    Server=servername:24106;User ID=username;Unicode=True;Password=password" 
    providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
    <add name="sdtp11" connectionString="Database=databasename;Server=servername:24106;
    Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Unicode=True;Password=password" 
    providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I created the `.config` file using the program 'EntLib Config' program. I am not sure what the problem is and have Googled it and have tried many .config files but without success. How to mitigate this error?

Comment: All I need to know what version of EL you use and what .Net framework you target with your application?

Comment: What is 'EL'?  I am targeting .Net 4.0.  I am using VS2013 and ODAC 12c.

Comment: What version of Enterprise Library (EL)?

Comment: Oh.  I am using EL 5.0.  I looked at the EL.Data version referenced in my project and its '5.0.505.0' so I updated my the versions in the .conf file and I got passed that error.  However, it fails when I call 'ExecuteNonQuery', {"Keyword not supported: 'database'."}  I am not sure if my config spec is still correct though.

Comment: Ok, you can use EL5 as long as your app is targets 4.0 and not 4.5. Did you create TNS names? If yes, can you test it in command line using `TNSPing`? just to make sure that you do have DB connectivity to start

Comment: But it looks as it is your actual query that fails: "Keyword not supported: 'database'." Check your query to be properly formed

Comment: It seems that I do not have TNSPing installed but I did get SQLPlus to connect to my database.

Comment: Intercept query you execute in `ExecuteNonQuery` and try it in SqlPlus. I wish you could test the string in your Config `alias="sdtp11" descriptor=...` Test whatever is in descriptor. It is possible - create test harness and create  ODP connection, use that string as connection string and try to open the connection.

Comment: Hey, I figured out what causing the Argument Exception "Keyword not supported: 'database'.  Its my connection string that you pointed to.  My connection string is <add name="OracleConnect" connectionString="Database=[databasename];Server=[servername]:24106;User ID=[username];Unicode=True;Password=[password]"             providerName="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />.  When I changed the "Database=" to Data "Source=", I know get a "ORA-12504: TNS:listener was not given the SERVICE_NAME in CONNECT_DATA" error which means my connection string is not correct.

Comment: So, I now have to figured out whats the correct connection string.  My TSNnames.ora has "[databasename]=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=[servername])(PORT=24106))
  (CONNECT_DATA=(SID=[databasename])))"

Comment: Well, for Odp, connection string is `Data source=;User Id=;Password=`. The TNS or Oracle connection should be 
  `DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = <server name>)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = <serv name>)
    )`
  THis is why I ALWAYS make sure of connection before anything else. http://www.connectionstrings.com/oracle-data-provider-for-net-odp-net/
 
But definitely looked looked and overlooked "database" in oracle connection

Comment: Ok - I got past that error.  My connection string is now connectionString="User ID=[username];Password=[password]; Data Source=[servername]:24106/[databasename]; Pooling=false;" but when I now execute the "ExecuteNonQuery" the number of rows I get back is -1.

Comment: What is the statement you executing,  UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE ?

Comment: Its "select table_name from all_tables where owner='[username]'"

Comment: If do not use the Enterprise library but with OracleConnection, OracleCommand classes and the ExecuteReader() method with the same string.  It works so does this mean that my connection string is still bad?

Comment: No, your query returns correct result (-1). `ExecuteNonQuery` only returns num of rows if you do  UPDATE, INSERT, or DELETE. Any other statement will be "-1". If the connection was bad there would be error

Comment: Ok but how can I see the results of the query?

Comment: To get results you can do DataReader or DataTable. For DT you need DataAdapter. Since you use EL, you should call something like, FillDataTable, i believe

Comment: Ok I think I got it! I used the ExecuteReader function to retrieve the results and its looks great!  Thank you for the help.  Question why does ExecuteNonQuery return -1 on a simple select statement?  That seems dumb.

Comment: Read the words - Execute Non Query. This method is not created to execute selects. How do you know records affected if you didn't read them to table or reader? And be careful with Recs affected. Because if you insert a row and you have a trigger on a view or table you insert to, and trigger modifies another record - it is going to be TOTAL record affected. So, you may expect 1 but get 2, or more.

Comment: Got it! I got the 'ExecuteNonQuery' from an example and ran with it but looking at it now it makes sense.  Thanks again for the great assistance. I definitely learn a few things along away!

Comment: You definitely made my day!

Comment: Ok then. you can delete your question now.